# Why does html5 geolocation output so many LAT decimals?

Tags: html

If you look at the output of a html5 geolocation request,
it has 14 LAT decimals.

https://www.w3schools.com/Html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

**I only find descriptions online, that 9 decimals are already
0,11mm exact.
Why are there 14 decimals?**

I can hardly believe, that GPS can tell you micrometer exact position.
And also, what for would that be good?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_precision

Answer (score 1):

Why? 1) to pursue precision. 2) to enable people interessed in many details, for their systems to work properly, to use them. 3) because it's very easy for developers like us, to ripoff the unnecessary (from our point of view) decimal parts.

Comment: So it is really micrometer exact?

Comment: It would be a nice question to be made on Google's headquarter. For a while, down here on heart, let's wait for a better answer.

Comment: @Roman excuse me sir, please feel free to check my answer as the correct one if you think it was useful to lead you to the right direction. Thank you.